# i am creating script that is going to login into remote server and and then do sudo to other user

Tags: shell

i am creating script  that is going to login into remote server and and then do sudo to other user. With that sudo user i want to run command with that user. Request to help!!!

```
ssh ${user}@${line} -qtt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null "sudo su - ${dict['sid_'$n]}adm; ls -ltr"
cd /usr/sap/${dict['sid_'$n]}
ls -tlr
```

`sudo su - sidadm`
then run the command

Comment: See if you can get your sysadmin to give your login user sudo privileges to execute that specific command so you don't have to interactively enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ssh <user>@<host> -qtt <other_ssh_options> "sudo su - <user_at_host> -c <command>"
```

Comment: its not working.. but i tried something which resulted me to get into the sudo user but after that its not going further. means after sudo, no command executed

Comment: user=$(whoami)
file=hostname.txt
echo "User is: $user"
while IFS= read -r line
do
#echo "==============$i======$line===========$n================================"
ssh ${user}@${line} -qtt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null "sudo su - ${dict['sid_'$n]}adm "
cd /usr/sap/JDT
ls -tlr

Comment: It seems that there is no command after sudo. Put ending double quote after command like `"sudo su - ${dict['sid_'$n]}adm  -c cd /usr/sap/JDT; ls -tlr"` and try.